# Network does not connect at boot

Tags: 12.04, networking

I am on 12.04, fresh install. When I boot, the boot screen says *Connecting to network*, later it is changed to something like *Did not connect, trying for another 60s*.

However, the network does not connect at the boot. But I can then log in without a network connection, and if I start a network manager service manually from the terminal with `sudo service network-manager start`, the network is connected without any problems.

Please, does anybody know where the problem could be? I don't want to wait more than two minutes every computer restart.

I am new to Ubuntu (and also to upstart) so I am a bit lost. There is no `/var/log/messages`, in dmesg I found this record, though it may not be related:

```
init: network-interface (eth1) pre-start process (492) terminated with status 1

init: network-interface (eth1) post-stop process (548) terminated with status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your BIOS settings is enabled with Network boot option.

Everytime it boots, it checks to see if there is a TFTP server sitting on the other side is giving image for network booting. This is not your case.

Since you already have a Ubuntu running locally, please go to BIOS during boot and disable the network boot option. Then your problem is resolved.

Concluding in a single line, just "Disable network boot option in BIOS settings".